# How to import classes and record an inventory?

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I have to write a program that import the classes created in “cars.py” and record inventory. However, I am lost in how to make the lists for each one and feel like I am overcomplicating the issue.

The result of the program when run should be similar to the one below;

```
USED CAR INVENTORY
===================

The following car is in inventory:

Make: BMW
Model: 2001
Mileage: 70000
Price: 15000.0
Number of doors: 4

The following pickup truck is in inventory.

Make: Toyota
Model: 2002
Mileage: 40000
Price: 12000.0
Drive type: 4WD

The following SUV is in inventory.

Make: Volvo
Model: 2000
Mileage: 30000
Price: 18500.0
Passenger Capacity: 5
```

my current program is

```
import cars


def write_invent():
    car_invent = []

    print "Enter data for the cars."

    num_cars = input("Enter number of cars: ")

    for count in range(1, num_cars):
        make = raw_input("Enter the make: ")
        model = input("Enter the year model: ")
        mileage = input("Enter the mileage: ")
        price = input("Enter the price: ")
        doors = input("Enter the number of doors: ")

        cars = cars.Car(make, model, mileage, price)

        car_invent.append(cars)

    return car_invent


def read_invent(car_invent, truck_invent, suv_invent):
    print "USED CAR INVENTORY"
    print "=================="
    print "The following car is in inventory."

    for item in car_invent:
        print "Make:" item.get_make()
        print "Model:" item.get_model()
        print "Mileage:" item.get_mileage()
        print "Price:" item.get_price()
        print "Number of doors:" item.get_doors()

    print "The following pickup truck is in inventory."

    for item in truck_invent:
        print "Make:" item.get_make()
        print "Model:" item.get_model()
        print "Mileage:" item.get_mileage()
        print "Price:" item.get_price()
        print "Drive type:" item.get_drive_type()


    print "The following SUV is in inventory."

    for item in suv_invent:
        print "Make:" item.get_make()
        print "Model:" item.get_model()
        print "Mileage:" item.get_mileage()
        print "Price:" item.get_price()
        print "Passenger Capacity:" item.get_pass_cap()


def menu():
    print "MENU"
    print "====="
    print "1. Enter data for inventory"
    print "2. Display inventory"
    print "3. Quit"

def main():
    menu()

    choice = input("Enter choice: ")
    while choice != 3:
        if choice == 1:
            write_invent()
            choice = input("Enter choice: ")

        elif choice == 2:
            read_invent()
            choice = input("Enter choice: ")

        else:
            print "Invalid choice"
            choice = input("Enter choice: ")

main()
```

Comment: So what's the *problem*? Give a [mcve], not just a code dump and a vague description.

Comment: How should I make and display the lists to show the data?

Comment: This isn't a tutorial service; if you don't know how to start, you aren't ready to ask a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what is your project specification but the code certainly looks okay. Just a small pointer.

Consider adding a function to just print basic car description. Like

```
def print_desc (vehicle):
    print "Make:" item.get_make()
    print "Model:" item.get_model()
    print "Mileage:" item.get_mileage()
    print "Price:" item.get_price()
```

Then modify your read_invent to call that. Example:

```
def read_invent(car_invent, truck_invent, suv_invent):
    print "USED CAR INVENTORY"
    print "=================="
    print "The following car is in inventory."

    for item in car_invent:
        print_desc(item)
        print "Number of doors:" item.get_doors()

    print "The following pickup truck is in inventory."

    for item in truck_invent:
        print_desc(item)
        print "Drive type:" item.get_drive_type()


    print "The following SUV is in inventory."

    for item in suv_invent:
        print_desc(item)
        print "Passenger Capacity:" item.get_pass_cap()
```

I might also consider adding a 'kind' property to the Car class to distinguish the type of vehicle.

This is so that you only need a generic list to represent your inventory. Which means your read_invent method can potentially be trimmed to take in just 1 list parameter.

```
def read_invent(inventory):
    print "USED CAR INVENTORY"
    print "=================="
    print "The following car is in inventory."

    for item in inventory:
        print "Make:" item.get_make()
        print "Model:" item.get_model()
        print "Mileage:" item.get_mileage()
        print "Price:" item.get_price()

        if item.kind == "CAR":
            print "Number of doors:" item.get_doors()
        elif item.kind == "SUV":
            print "Passenger Capacity:" item.get_pass_cap()
        elif item.kind == "TRUCK":
            print "Drive type:" item.get_drive_type()
```